# Error in a for loop when "dealing" out cards? Java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create a game of war through Java and I'm getting some errors, I've tried to change the way I deal out the cards 20 times now, I still can't figure it out and it's annoying me to death! Sometimes the code will stop mid way through dealing out the cards and will play the game out. Was wondering if anyone could help me fix the error it's giving me in giveCards(), thanks! Also, I know that this is the MAIN problem, I'm sure I can fix any others I have!

**ERROR**
*5_hearts was given to player 1 : Player card draw turn = 0

51

7_hearts was given to player 2 : Player card draw turn = 1

50

8_spades was given to player 1 : Player card draw turn = 2

49

2_hearts was given to player 2 : Player card draw turn = 3

48

jack_spades was given to player 1 : Player card draw turn = 4

47

7_diamond was given to player 2 : Player card draw turn = 5

46

ace_hearts was given to player 1 : Player card draw turn = 6

45

9_spades was given to player 2 : Player card draw turn = 7

44

3_spades was given to player 1 : Player card draw turn = 8

43

2_diamond was given to player 2 : Player card draw turn = 9

42

jack_diamond was given to player 1 : Player card draw turn = 10

41

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 41,       Size: 41

    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)

    at me.canyon.Cards.giveCards(Cards.java:214)

    at me.canyon.Cards.createCards(Cards.java:88)

    at me.canyon.Cards.main(Cards.java:18)*

**CODE**

```
static int round = 0;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    createCards();
}

//TODO Create a better way of doing this???
public static void createCards() {
    cards.add("ace_diamond");
    cards.add("ace_spades");
    cards.add("ace_clubs");
    cards.add("ace_hearts");

    cards.add("2_diamond");
    cards.add("2_spades");
    cards.add("2_clubs");
    cards.add("2_hearts");

    cards.add("3_diamond");
    cards.add("3_spades");
    cards.add("3_clubs");
    cards.add("3_hearts");

    cards.add("4_diamond");
    cards.add("4_spades");
    cards.add("4_clubs");
    cards.add("4_hearts");

    cards.add("5_diamond");
    cards.add("5_spades");
    cards.add("5_clubs");
    cards.add("5_hearts");

    cards.add("6_diamond");
    cards.add("6_spades");
    cards.add("6_clubs");
    cards.add("6_hearts");

    cards.add("7_diamond");
    cards.add("7_spades");
    cards.add("7_clubs");
    cards.add("7_hearts");

    cards.add("8_diamond");
    cards.add("8_spades");
    cards.add("8_clubs");
    cards.add("8_hearts");

    cards.add("9_diamond");
    cards.add("9_spades");
    cards.add("9_clubs");
    cards.add("9_hearts");

    cards.add("10_diamond");
    cards.add("10_spades");
    cards.add("10_clubs");
    cards.add("10_hearts");

    cards.add("jack_diamond");
    cards.add("jack_spades");
    cards.add("jack_clubs");
    cards.add("jack_hearts");

    cards.add("queen_diamond");
    cards.add("queen_spades");
    cards.add("queen_clubs");
    cards.add("queen_hearts");

    cards.add("king_diamond");
    cards.add("king_spades");
    cards.add("king_clubs");
    cards.add("king_hearts");

    giveCards();
}


public static String getSuit(String card) {
    String[] suit = card.split("_");
    return suit[1];
}

public static String getCard(String card) {
    String[] cardType = card.split("_");
    return cardType[0]; 

}

public static String cardCompare(String card1, String card2) {
    int card1Number = 0;
    int card2Number = 0;
    int card1NumberSuit;
    int card2NumberSuit;

    if (getSuit(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("spades"))
        card1NumberSuit = 4;
    else if (getSuit(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("hearts"))
        card1NumberSuit = 3;
    else if (getSuit(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("diamond"))
        card1NumberSuit = 2;
    else
        card1NumberSuit = 1;

    if (getSuit(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("spades"))
        card2NumberSuit = 4;
    else if (getSuit(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("hearts"))
        card2NumberSuit = 3;
    else if (getSuit(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("diamond"))
        card2NumberSuit = 2;
    else
        card2NumberSuit = 1;

    if(getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("ace"))
        card1Number = 12;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("king"))
        card1Number = 11;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("queen"))
        card1Number = 10;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("jack"))
        card1Number = 9;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("10"))
        card1Number = 8;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("9"))
        card1Number = 7;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("8"))
        card1Number = 6;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("7"))
        card1Number = 5;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("6"))
        card1Number = 4;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("5"))
        card1Number = 3;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
        card1Number = 2;
    else if (getCard(card1).equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
        card1Number = 1;
    else
        card1Number = 0;

    if(getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("ace"))
        card2Number = 12;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("king"))
        card2Number = 11;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("queen"))
        card2Number = 10;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("jack"))
        card2Number = 9;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("10"))
        card2Number = 8;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("9"))
        card2Number = 7;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("8"))
        card2Number = 6;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("7"))
        card2Number = 5;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("6"))
        card2Number = 4;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("5"))
        card2Number = 3;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
        card2Number = 2;
    else if (getCard(card2).equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
        card2Number = 1;
    else
        card2Number = 0;

    if (card1Number > card2Number)
        return card1;
    else if (card2Number < card2Number)
        return card2;
    else {
        if (card1NumberSuit > card2NumberSuit)
            return card1;
        else if (card2NumberSuit > card1NumberSuit)
            return card2;
        else
            return "no one, it was a tie";
    }
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max)
{
     Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
}


public static void giveCards() {
        for (int p = 0; p <= cards.size(); p++) {
            int cardNumber = randInt(1, cards.size());  
            //Player 1
            if ((p & 1) == 0) {
                player1Cards.add(cards.get(cardNumber));
                System.out.println(cards.get(cardNumber) + " was given to player 1 : Player card draw turn = " + p);
            }
            else {
                player2Cards.add(cards.get(cardNumber)); 
                System.out.println(cards.get(cardNumber) + " was given to player 2 : Player card draw turn = " + p);
                }
            cards.remove(cardNumber);
            System.out.println(cards.size());

            if (cards.size() == 0) 
                playGame();
        } 
}

public static int getRandomCardPlayer1() {
    int deckSize = player1Cards.size();
    return randInt(1, deckSize);
}

public static int getRandomCardPlayer2() {
    int deckSize = player2Cards.size();
    return randInt(1, deckSize);
}

public static void playGame() { 
    //Create the delay executor (1 second delay on every play)
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Making sure both players still have cards
            if ((player1Cards.size() != 0) && (player2Cards.size() != 0)) {

                //Gets a random card from the players decks
                int player1CardNumber = getRandomCardPlayer1();
                int player2CardNumber = getRandomCardPlayer2();

                //Converts the cardNumber to a String
                String player1Card = player1Cards.get(player1CardNumber);
                String player2Card = player2Cards.get(player2CardNumber);

                //Adds 1 to round to keep track of amount of rounds total
                round++;

                //Compares the two given cards
                String winner = cardCompare(player1Card, player2Card);

                //Based off winner, a player either loses or gains a card
                if (winner.equals(player1Card)) {
                    player2Cards.remove(player2CardNumber);
                    player1Cards.add(player2Card);
                } else if (winner.equals(player2Card)) {
                    player1Cards.remove(player1CardNumber);
                    player2Cards.add(player1Card);
                } 

                //Output
                System.out.println("Player 1 flipped a " + player1Card);
                System.out.println("Player 2 flipped a " + player2Card);
                System.out.println("The winner of round " + round +" is " + winner + "!");
                System.out.println("---------=========| Next Round! |==========----------");
            } else if (player1Cards.size() == 0)
                System.out.println("Player 2 wins!");
            else
                System.out.println("Player 1 wins!");
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minus ***1*** in your randomly generated `cardNumber`

`cardNumber = randInt(1, cards.size() - 1);`

minus ***1*** in your `for loop` condition `p <= cards.size() - 1`

> cards.size() = 41 but if we count from 0 to 40 it counts 41

And your exception is occurred because

> when randomly generated `cardNumber` is 41 then `cards.get(41)` it doesn't find any value there and gives array index out of bound error

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much, the game is practically working at this point, just a few minor things I'll finish up in the morning, I HIGHLY appreciate your help and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

```
p <= cards.size()
```

change it to

```
p < cards.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays starts at index 0 and ends at index `length - 1`. Your `randInt` method should just take the `cards.size()` as its bound because the bound is exclusive.